# Fixed navbar brings dropdown to front

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I am trying to make a fixed navigation bar with animated dropdown, therefore I used `z-index` stacking instead of `display:none`. However, this dropdown inherits the `z-index` property from the navigation bar, which has the stacking index of 99999. Hence it brings the dropdown menu to front, overlapping other contents. As a result, when the users move their cursor to the spot where the dropdown occupies, it appears. I posted an image for a better illustration.

[image]

HTML Markup

```
<li class="ic-quick-nav-items ic-quick-nav-items--dropdown">
    <button class="ic-quick-nav-dropdown">Listening <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></button>
    <ul class="ic-dropdown">
        <li class="ic-dropdown-items"><a href="#" class="ic-dropdown-links" tabindex="-1">Listening Practice</a></li>
         <li class="ic-dropdown-items"><a href="#" class="ic-dropdown-links" tabindex="-1">Tips & Tricks</a></li>
     </ul></li>
```

This is my CSS code for the whole navbar:

```
#ic-nav-border {
    border-top:1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
}
.ic-quick-nav-items--dropdown {
    position:relative;
}
.ic-quick-nav-items--dropdown:hover  .ic-dropdown {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:5;
    top:42px;
}
.ic-quick-nav-dropdown {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:0;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:11.5px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:color 0.4s;
    -o-transition:color 0.4s;
    -moz-transition:color 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition:color 0.4s;
}
.ic-quick-nav-dropdown:hover, .ic-quick-nav-dropdown:active, .ic-quick-nav-dropdown:focus {
    color:rgba(215, 84, 77, 1);
}
.ic-dropdown {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:80px;
    list-style:none;
    visibility: none;
    opacity:0;
    padding:20px;
    min-width:120px;
    z-index:-1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #eee;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
}
```

Fixed navbar set by jQuery, results in inline CSS code

```
<div class="ic-header-part-wrapper header-sticky theme-light" id="ic-nav-border" style="position: fixed; z-index: 99999; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;">
```

What stacking solution should I apply in order to make dropdown stays behind and the navbar stays fixed at the top?

**Edit:** Actually, the whole navigation is sticky, therefore it has two state: static and fixed. In static state it works fine, however in fixed state it does not

Comment: what's the intended animation?

Comment: @FacundoCorradini from top:80px to top:42px

Comment: so.. they should start being invisible, and on hover of the parent become visible and animate from 0 to 1 opacity, and from 80px bellow the parent to14px?

Comment: @FacundoCorradini the problem is not the animation, it works fine, but the fixed navigation bar brings the dropdown too high that the users don't need to hover the links to make it visible, and because it overlaps other contents, when the users hover the part that the dropdown occupied, it appears. Please have a look at my photo.

Comment: I know it's not the animation, just trying to understand why you are trying to use z-index for that.

Comment: @FacundoCorradini, since z-index makes it stay behind at the beginning, and when the parent is hovered, I use z-index to make it stay in front, the use opacity and visibility to create the animation. And the navbar is sticky, actually, so it has to state: static and fixed. In static state it works fine, while in fixed state it does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, it looks like the only error there is the incorrect property value on `visibility` for `.ic-dropdown`, as you stated `none` where should be `hidden`.

Therefore, your `visibility` is not applying, and the element is only "hidden" because of the `opacity`, which holds the pointer-events. So when you mouse over the space it occupies, it still triggers the animation.

So fix the `.ic-dropdown{visibility:hidden}` and it should work OK. You can get rid of all z-indexes there, I'm still not sure why are you using them to begin with.